# How to make previous_post_link into an image

Tags: navigation

I would like to make the previous and next post link into an image instead of a link text
e.g.

```
<a href="%link"><img src=""  /> </a>
```

so whatever the size of the image it would be clickable
i tried adding a css through filter but the image just stays as a background(not clickable)

```
function post_left_attributes($output) {
    $injection = 'class="arrow_left"';

    return str_replace('<a href=', '<a '.$injection.' href=', $output);
}

function post_right_attributes($output) {
    $injection = 'class="arrow_right"';
    return str_replace('<a href=', '<a '.$injection.' href=', $output);
}
```

Comment: they are different (not looking for featured image but make the next and previous into image only )

Comment: The 1st parameter is $format. You can use that for your image

Comment: If its for arrows, you could use dashicons

Answer (score 0):

You can customize [previous_post_link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link) like this

```
previous_post_link('%link','<img src="link_to_image"/>');
```